# Complex object in ASP.NET WEB API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Got an app that makes Get requests with some parameters to my old api now I want to make a new api using .Net MVC6 but I cannot change all the clients for them to use a different Uri.

I need to make my new api compatible with those kind of requests.The query style is this: `localhost/api/locations?location[lat]=12&location[lng]=21`

```
public class Location
{
    public string lat;
    public string lng;
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class LocationsController : Controller
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(Location loc)
    { 
        var av=   new CreatedAtActionResult("","",null,null);
        return av;
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I bind this "kind" of query to the parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy thing to do would be to override the parameters names:

```
public ActionResult Get([FromUri(Name = "location[lat]")]string lat, [FromUri(Name = "location[lng]")]string lng)
{
}
```

Alternativelly you could implement a custom TypeConverter or ModelBinder.

You could find a nice overview of all the different possibilities here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

---

Update:
I've found a similar question on  [Changing the parameter name Web Api model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600275/changing-the-parameter-name-web-api-model-binding)

Comment: Does it work with asp.net core 1.0? (I'm still a bit lost with all this versions)

Comment: If you use .Net Core you should use MVC 6 instead of Web Api 2

Comment: After doing some research and talk with some colleagues this is the best option. this actually worked out so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your api by doing this:

`api/locations?lat=xxx&lng=zzz`

Comment: made an edit to my question. but the problem is that I cannot change how the request is made.

Comment: You may need to implement a custom `IModelBinder`