# Changing the parameter name Web Api binding for Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, uri, model-binding

On StackOverflow there are Question about Changing the parameter name in Web Api for model binding --> [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600275/changing-the-parameter-name-web-api-model-binding)

As I currently works with such type of binding using `FromURI` I've also tried to make URI shorter using `FromURI(Name='...')`.

But I have one question (can't find answer in Google) - Is it possible to set `Name` parameter for Model?

For example :

- Web API GET  Method :

  `[HttpGet]
  public async Task<List<string>> Get([FromUri]SearchModel searchObj)`
- SearchModel  Model

  `public class SearchModel
  {
      public string UserName { get; set; }
      public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
      public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
      public DayTypes? Type { get; set; }
  }`

So Is it possible to send request to server with such URI params that can init Model:

```
?u=test&s=2016-01-01&e=2016-04-04&t=DayOff
```

Where

- `u` is `UserName`
- `s` is `StartDate`
- `e` is `EndDate`
- `t` is `Type`

Comment: Did You solved this?

Comment: @Misiu, No, I pass query params as long as they are