# ASP.NET Web API model binding - different parameters names

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to map parameters from request to properties with different names? I need it because I'd like to use words splitted by underscore as url parameters but in C# code I'd like to use normal convention. Example :

```
?property_name=1 to property PropertyName
```

In the request I use `[FromUri]` parameter like

```
public IHttpActionResult DoMethod([FromUri(Name = "")] SomeInput input)
```

Initially I thought that model binding is performed by Json serializer but probably it isn't. I tried DataMember attribute as well but these approaches do not work.

```
public class SomeInput
{
    [JsonProperty("property_name")]
    [DataMember(Name = "property_name")]
    public int PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

I read about the custom binders but I hope some more simple way must exist.
Any idea how to do this correctly and simple in ASP.NET Web API 2 with using Owin and Katana?

Comment: Did you make some changes in your web api configuration? like: formatters, converters etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the parameter name Web Api model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26600275/5815327)
This answer specifically worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29090053/5815327

Answer (score 4):

You can do a remapping for an individual parameter using the `Name` property on `[FromUri]`:

```
public IHttpActionResult DoMethod([FromUri(Name = "property_name")] int propertyName)
```

To remap inside a custom object you will need to create a model binder.

Comment: It is no solution. I have multiple properties inside SomeInput. I use only simplified code in this example.

Comment: You can do this for as many properties as you'd like. Obviously, it's tedious with a lot of fields.

Comment: Yes yo're right but I have more things in wrapping object SomeInput like validations, comments to generate documentation etc.

Comment: You can always build that object with these fields.

Answer (score 0):

In your model you could do something like this.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public class SomeInput
{
  [FromQuery(Name = "property_name")]
  public string PropertyName {get; set;}
    
}
```

Then in your controller get method access it from the mapped name

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult DoMethod([FromQuery]SomeInput someInput)
{
 someInput.PropertyName 
 ...
}
```